# When I run my script using the c shell in UNIX, I get this error "var not found [No such file or directory]". How do I fix this?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to run a simple script in UNIX

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME="Joshua"
CAR="Volvo"
AGE = 16

if ("$AGE" < 15) then
echo $NAME "is not old enough to drive a" $CAR
else
echo $NAME "is old enough to drive a" $CAR
fi
```

I tried using a simple if then else statement and I keep getting these errors after running it:

`./myScript.sh[5]: AGE: not found [No such file or directory]`

`./myScript.sh[7]: 15: cannot open [No such file or directory]`

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Should be `AGE=16`

Comment: Agree with above, BUT your title says C shell, (i.e. `csh`) , but  your first line says `#/bin/sh`. change to `#!/bin/csh` and get some very diferent error messages. `set var = "value" is the proper form for `csh`. your `if` statement looks correct for `csh` but not `sh`. Good luck.

Comment: Removed tag "Windows" since this question relates to unix / linux

Comment: Maybe will be wise to use canonical `if`: `if [ "$AGE" -lt 15 ] then`